# Not work when use -I(capital i) in gcc in makefile

Tags: c, github, gcc, makefile, gnu

I am writing a Makefile to run my c program.

The directory and files are shown below,
[image]

And here is my codes in Makefile

```
all: perimeter.o main.c 
    gcc -o program main.c perimeter.o

perimeter.o: perimeter.c perimeter.h
    gcc -c perimeter.c

clean:
    find ./ -executable -delete

test: tests

tests: test.o
    gcc -o tests test.o

test.o: ./tests/test.c
    gcc -c ./tests/test.c -I..
```

However, the header files can not be found

[image]

Then I tried...

```
test.o: ./tests/test.c perimeter.h
    gcc -c ./tests/test.c -I..
```

and

```
test.o: ./tests/test.c perimeter.h
    gcc -c ./tests/test.c -I ../
```

and

```
test.o: ./tests/test.c perimeter.h
    gcc -c ./tests/test.c
```

All Failed

So I think `-I..` is not work.(I also tried `-I ../`)

How to solve this problem?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script expects the CWD to be the directory containing `Makefile` (since it uses `perimiter.c` and `./tests/test.c`), so `perimiter.h` is in the CWD, so

```bash
gcc -c ./tests/test.c -I..
```

should be

```bash
gcc -c ./tests/test.c -I.
```